# why the if condition is always true?

Tags: c

*hi, i don't understand why this if condition don't need any "condition" and is always true.*

```
  #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        char text[] = "I learn C programming because it’s fun";
        char *ptr, c = 'u';
        ptr = strrchr(text, c);

        if (ptr)
        {
            printf("The position of ’%c’ is: %d\n", c, ptr-text);
        }

        printf("The character was not found\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: the only `false` condition is `0`; since `ptr` is not `0` (`null`) `if` treats it as `true`

Comment: `if (ptr) ...` is the same as `if (ptr != NULL) ...`

Comment: The reason for doing this is just to check to make sure that the pointer `ptr` is not null before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> why the if condition is always true?

Because `'u'` is in the string.

Try

```
ptr = strrchr(text, 'q');
```

and see what happens.

`strrchr` returns a pointer to the character searched for or **NULL** when the character isn't found.

As for:

> ... why this if condition don't need any "condition"

In C anything that can be converted to an integer value can be used as a condition. Example:

```
int x = 42;
if (x)
{
    // do something
}
```

Here `x` is a condition. It is the same as saying

```
int x = 42;
if (x != 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

Anything that isn't "zero" are considered TRUE in C.

This goes for pointers as well:

```
int* p = NULL;
p = whatever...;
if (p)
{
    // do something isn't NULL
}
else
{
    // p is NULL so do something else
}
```

which can also be written as:

```
int* p = NULL;
p = whatever...;
if (p != NULL)   
{
    // do something isn't NULL
}
else
{
    // p is NULL so do something else
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't get your comment. I copied the question directly: "why the if condition is always true?" I don't see what other answer one could give

Comment: @EugeneSh. well.. ok... maybe I only answered half the Q. Added the second half